# How to set the text below the icon in TabLayout Android?

Tags: android, tabs

I have a tablyout having tabs with both icons and text.
But the text is coming in right of icon,
I want text to come below icon.How to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Add Custom Layout :

```
Tab tab = tabLayout.newTab();
tab.setCustomLayout( R.layout.whatever );
tabLayout.addTab(add);
```

Your layout would be a simple TextView with a DrawableRight that specifies your icon.

For more: [Support Tab Layout](http://panavtec.me/playing-with-the-new-support-tablayout)

Answer (score 0):

this link teaches all about tabLayout

[Android Material Design working with Tabs](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/)